# How to update or refresh table using Rails Actioncable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, actioncable

My action cable is working fine, it shows me an alert with the data content(although it shows in all the pages).

This is my case: an user with role ADMIN has access to an url (http://localhost:3000/ventas/) with a table (html id=tablaventas)that show a list of sales. This table must be automatically refreshed every time a user (role SELLER) inserts a new sale in the database.

This user with role seller has an url (http://localhost:3000/ventas/new) with a form where insert new sales to the database. The Actioncable implementation is working okay, but I have two problems:

1- how to refresh the table from the ventas.coffee:

```
//here i am stuck
 received: (data) ->
   alert data.name  //this works ok
   //...AND HERE I WANT TO UPDATE or refresh THE ADMIN TABLE
```

2- Also, how can I show for example the alert message only to the admin specific view? in this case only in the view ventas/index.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you just add another row to the table?

`$('#tablaventas').append("<tr><td>#{data.name}</td>...other tds...</tr>")`

If you need to refresh the whole table - you'll need to call `.html(data.table_html)` on table container element. Also this means that you'll have to render table_html in your controller, via `render_to_string('table')` or something.

2. I think your issue is that you subscribe to action cable updates globally while you only need to subscribe on the index page. This [blog post](http://philippe.bourgau.net/how-to-subscribe-to-an-actioncable-channel-on-a-specific-page-with-custom-data/) should help you solve this.

Hope the above helps.